# Image does not change when changing new url in React Native

Tags: react-native, image, react-component, rerender

I'm using lib `react-native-fast-image` for the display of his image.

But i'm having a problem that my image is **not refreshing after enter new url**, I have also called setState again. I use Hook

I have learned that adding time to the link to fix it, below:

`setImage(PING_PUSH_MEDIA + respone + '?' + new Date().getTime());`

But this results in the **image flicker** every time the state changes

I'm testing on android, but seems to have the same problem on iOS too

Is there a problem with my url image? My image path is http not https, but it also doesn't seem to work on https.

I also used cache mode as **immutable**, but why is it still not working?

```
<FastImage
       source={{
         uri: PING_PUSH_MEDIA + profile?.avatar,
       }}
       style={styles.itemAvatar}
       cache={FastImage.cacheControl.immutable}
/>
```

Please, help me. Thanks all !

Comment: could you solve this problem? I'm with the same?

Comment: @EmmanuelGarciaMartinez hi you, i'm resolved, I'm pretty dumb about this, because I changed the image but the path didn't change, I'm resolved after change path with every new image